# Boolean logic transformation rule explaining this switch to a Java ==?

Tags: java, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I'm going through exercices on CodingBat. On this [page](http://codingbat.com/prob/p181646) there is this mention in the solution:

```
  // The above can be shortened to:
  //   return ((aSmile && bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile));
  // Or this very short version (think about how this is the same as the above)
  //   return (aSmile == bSmile);
```

Is there any rule that explains the short version? How do you go from a logical AND to an equals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First condition basically says: If both are true or both are false. That happens only when they are equal.

Note that in Java there is a trap for Boolean objects where both of the following will print:

```
Boolean aSmile=new Boolean(true),bSmile=new Boolean(true);
if((aSmile & bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile)) { System.out.println("SAME"); }
if(aSmile!=bSmile)                            { System.out.println("NOT THE SAME"); }
```

Comment: Provided A & B are not objects *or* the language is not Java.  In java, with Boolean objects, A==B means they are the same *object* whereas the first test will actually test the boolean values of the objects. :-)

Comment: If they were objects in Java... the first line would have failed compilation :)

Comment: No, Boolean objects would be auto-unboxed.

Comment: And Boolean objects compared with == don't get unboxed?

Comment: This exercice itself is in Java. Since these are Booleans, autoboxing is used in more recents of Java. So this would like manipulating primitive booleans ?

Comment: A trap being that if Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE are used, the second test will work, but using new Boolean(true) and new Boolean(false) will fail, though the latter is an anti-pattern, so broken code may work for a very long time.

Comment: Good to know. As there's only one false and one true... it never crossed my mind to question if there's need for unboxing in the Boolean case. That would make for a nice question on SO actually.

Comment: @James: Be careful to distinguish between `boolean` primatives and `Boolean` objects; the code will work for primatives, but ***may*** fail for objects per my earlier comment.

Comment: It actually makes sense philosophically: Boolean better_true = new Boolean(true); if(true == better_true) { System.out.println("true is absolute... no better alternative exists"); } ... while as for ... Boolean my_true = new Boolean(true); Boolean your_true = new Boolean(true); if(my_true != your_true) { System.out.println("my true is always different than your true"); }

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey Ok. This is very interesting information so thanks for sharing. What exactly is happening when you use this new anti-pattern ?

Comment: @James: You are creating a new boolean object with a true or false value; but it's always unnecessary since there are only two values you can always use `Boolean bool=(expression ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE)` (old JVM) or `Boolean bool=expression` (Java 5+) JVM) in place of `Boolean bool=new Boolean(expression)`.

Comment: Ah ok. So `==` IS comparing the object hash codes. And two different objects are being created ? So the objects could be compared using `equals` as is advised for Strings (despite object pooling...).

Comment: Right. So equal in Java is playing the role of equivalence (<=>) in boolean logic.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to explain the equivalency of these two expressions is to create a logic table:

```
aSmile  |  bSmile
   0         0     1
   0         1     0
   1         0     0
   1         1     1
```

Plugging all the combinations of a & b into the first expression you can see that the first expression is only true when aSmile and bSmile are equal. So aSmile == bSmile will return true only when they are both equal.

Comment: Thanks. If you know of a theoretical rule (just logic) then that would be a nice bonus. But the transformation has been clearly illustrated here.

Comment: Just given this a thought. This is the behaviour of the equivalence (<=>) operator. Now all that I need to do is figure out if the expression can be simplified in the same way in theory.

Answer (score 2):

If `(aSmile && bSmile)` evalutes true, then BOTH are true.

If `(!aSmile && !bSmile)` evaluates true, then BOTH are false.

Therefore, if either one of these conditions (both TRUE, or both FALSE) are true, the long version returns TRUE.

Asked most simply (as in the short version), are aSmile and bSmile equivalent?

Comment: So this is logical equivalence. Thanks for confirming :)